# Fail to Insert Unicode into SQL Server using Peta Poco

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8, petapoco

Normally when we want to insert unicode letter into SQL Server, we can do N' foreign letter'
But I'm using **Peta Poco** and I cannot add **N** (or I don't know how to)

So how do I make sure my input can be saved as unicode (my table columns are `nvarchar`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PetaPoco supports Unicode and will save your unicode strings just right if your original string is Unicode (the page or program you are using is unicode)